# Exception while computing database live data - crash during migration

Tags: android, android-room, commonsware-cwac, sqlcipher-android

I'm using cwac-saferoom version 1.0.4 
And some of the devices are getting this issue right after updating the app to a new version.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing
>   database live data.
>          at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(SourceFile:6)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

**Another part of logs from the sqlcipher itself is :**

> Caused by net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a
>   database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(SourceFile)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SourceFile:3)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.(SourceFile:12)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.(SourceFile:18)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.(SourceFile:1)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SourceFile:9)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SourceFile:5)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SourceFile:1)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.keyDatabase(SourceFile:6)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabaseInternal(SourceFile:4)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SourceFile:10)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SourceFile:8)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SourceFile:14)
>          at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SourceFile:2)
>          at com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper$OpenHelper.getWritableSupportDatabase(SourceFile:2)
>          at com.commonsware.cwac.saferoom.Helper.getWritableDatabase(SourceFile:5)
>          at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.createInvalidationTracker(SourceFile:25)
>                                        createOpenHelper
>                                        inTransaction
>          at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotSuspendingTransaction(SourceFile:3)
>          at androidx.room.RoomDatabase.createInvalidationTracker(SourceFile:18)
>                                        createOpenHelper
>                                        query
>          at androidx.room.util.DBUtil.query(SourceFile:1)
>          at com.myapp.MainActivity$onResume$2.onChanged(SourceFile:1)
>          at com.myapp.MainActivity$onResume$2.call(SourceFile:1)
>          at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(SourceFile:5)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>          at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>          at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: What is different about the new app version compared to the previous one? Are you using a new version of SafeRoom, and if so, what was the old version? Are you upgrading your database schema? BTW, when posting stack traces here, you might want to de-obfuscate them.

Comment: Had an older version of saferoom - 1.0.2 and moved to 1.0.4 3 days ago. 
At first i tried Migrating to the New Format which yielded 

`Caused by net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: file is not a database: , while compiling: select count(*) from sqlite_master;`

Trying to avoid it = i just moved to a new file name and had the db created from scratch. 

Still got the same results - 1 issue is the file is not a database and the second one is this

Comment: 1.0.2 and 1.0.4 use the same database format -- the database format change occurred between 0.x and 1.0.0. Beyond that, I don't have much to go on. "not an error" is a generic message from SQLite (not even SQLCipher, let alone SafeRoom). If you work out a reproducible test case, file an issue with it on the SafeRoom repo, and I can take a look at it.

Comment: Yes, i had to migrate from 0.x to 1.x and since then the issues appeared. 
But since then i created a new name for the db without migration and i still get the issues stated. 
I will try to create a proper test case.

Answer (score 0):

safeRoom is retired and no longer supported. Consider using sqlcipher.

https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher#using-sqlcipher-for-android-with-room